# Please hel with syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am getting the following error:

---

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''login' ('id', 'uname', email', 'pass') VALUES (NULL, 'X', 'X' at line 1
```

---

The code is as follows:

---

```
<?php

    require('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //Perform the verification
        $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
        $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
        $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
        $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

        if($email1 == $email2){
            if($pass1 == $pass2){
                //All good. Carry on.

                $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
                $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
                $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
                $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
                $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'login' 
                                ('id', 'uname', email', 'pass') 
                        VALUES (NULL, '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')") or die(mysql_error());

            }else{
                echo "Passwords do not match.<br />";
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            echo "Emails do not match.<br /><br />";
            exit();
        }
```

---

Can somebody please push me in right direction

Kind regards,

Comment: you've quoted (not used backticks "`") your table and field names - that's why it's a syntax error

Comment: You should consider using PHP's mysqli or PDO extensions. The mysql extension is deprecated an may be removed from future releases: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Use back ticks not single quotes for table names and column names.  Please read through this for further explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `login` (`id`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Just to point out other problems, in your query although the usage of "single quote" is not correct, you had a missing opening "single quote" in the `email` column.

Also note that `mysql_` extensions are deprecated so start looking into implementing `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape field and table names with ` character, ' is only values delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather escape table name and column names with backtick instead of an apostrophe.